# android code to keep recording a video and should save only last 10minutes of the video in the sd card

Tags: android, facebook, video, uri

```
Android code to keep recording a video and should save only last 10minutes of the video in the sd card?
```

My code is recording and saving the video inside the sd card but just after the camera gets closed i am getting an error with force close message.When I am using the camera.open() , camera.release() and camera.unlock() methods I am receiving an error that it is undefined.
my code is as below:
    package com.example.myapp2;

```
import java.io.File;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Camera;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    // Activity request codes
    private static final int CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE = 200;
    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = 2;
    // directory name to store captured images and videos
    private static final String VIDEO_DIRECTORY_NAME = "Hello Camera";
    private Uri fileUri; // file url to store image/video
    // VideoView videoPreview;
    Button preview,buttonRecordVideo;
    Camera camera;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  
        buttonRecordVideo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRecordVideo);  
       /**
         * Record video button click event
         */        
        buttonRecordVideo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // record video
                recordVideo();
            }
        });
        // Checking camera availability
        if (!isDeviceSupportCamera()) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! Your device doesn't support camera",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // will close the app if the device does't have camera
            finish();
        }
    }

   /*
     * Checking device has camera hardware or not
     */
    private boolean isDeviceSupportCamera() {
        if (getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
                PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
            // this device has a camera
            return true;
        } else {
            // no camera on this device
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Here we store the file url as it will be null after returning from camera
     * app
     */
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        // save file url in bundle as it will be null on scren orientation
        // changes
        outState.putParcelable("file_uri", fileUri);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        // get the file url
        fileUri = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("file_uri");
    }

    /**
     * Recording video
     */
    private void recordVideo() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);

        fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO);

        // set video quality
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);

        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); // set the image file
                                                            // name
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, 6); //restricting video by time limit(seconds)
        // intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SIZE_LIMIT,1317961L); //restricting video by using memory size(BYTES)
        // start the video capture Intent
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    /**
     * Receiving activity result method will be called after closing the camera
     * */

    @Override 
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // if the result is capturing Image
       if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // video successfully recorded
                // preview the recorded video
                release();
               // previewVideo();
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // user cancelled recording
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "User cancelled video recording", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();

            } else {
                // failed to record video
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! Failed to record video", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    } 

    public final void release()
    {
        camera.save();
    }


    /**
     * ------------ Helper Methods ----------------------
     * */

    /**
     * Creating file uri to store image/video
     */
    public Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type) {
        return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
    }

    /**
     * returning image / video
     */
    private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {

        // External sdcard location
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(
                Environment
                        .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                VIDEO_DIRECTORY_NAME);

        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.d(VIDEO_DIRECTORY_NAME, "Oops! Failed create "
                        + VIDEO_DIRECTORY_NAME + " directory");
                return null;
            }
        }

        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
                Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                    + "VID_" + timeStamp + ".mp4");
        } else {
            return null;
        }

        return mediaFile;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: post the log please....

Comment: 10-23 09:29:06.398: E/AndroidRuntime(7575): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-23 09:29:06.398: E/AndroidRuntime(7575): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-23 09:29:06.398: E/AndroidRuntime(7575):  at java.io.File.fixSlashes(File.java:205)

Answer (score 0):

In your code , you have declared a class level variable `Camera camera` but you are not at all using it anywhere, infact you haven't even initialized it, so it stays null, throughout your code and hence the exception.

What you are doing is , using an intent to record the video. If you want to create a custom video recorder, check [this documentation here by developers.android.com](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html). It has avery nice and detailed solution to your problem **(with code**)

Mark this as accepted answer if this solves your problem. :)